# No Pyramid Debug Toolbar on a real (VPS) server with development.ini

Tags: python, pyramid

I'm deploying my project to a VPS server and I want to test it with the [Pyramid Debug Toolbar](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_debugtoolbar) running. Site works fine, but the Toolbar does not appear at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`debugtoolbar.hosts` is the relevant setting that you should be caring about. By default it only displays the toolbar for requests from localhost.

http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_debugtoolbar/en/latest/#settings

Comment: The only question is in what format I need to write debugtoolbar.hosts? [‘127.0.0.1 my_IP’, ‘::1’] or what? Thanks for your help!

Comment: From the documentation I linked: "This should be a list or, if defined in a Paste ini file, a single-line list of IP addresses separated by spaces."